# sass mixins with loops givies error

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, mixins

I'm writing a sass code to get css output as given below.

```
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 50%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, 50%);
 background: linear-gradient(top, 50%);
```

The sass mixin code i wrote for this is:

```
@mixin linear-gradient($name, $arg1, $arg2){
    @each $vendor in ('-webkit-', '-moz-','') {
        background: #{$vendor}#{$name}(#{$arg1}, #{$arg2});
    }
}
@include linear-gradient(linear-gradient, top, 50%);
```

But i was getting error. Can anyone tell why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$name` parameter seems unnecessary so I've omitted it from my first example. The second example shows an alternative solution using `$name` so that it compiles the parentheses properly.

```
@mixin linear-gradient($arg1, $arg2){
    @each $vendor in ('-webkit-', '-moz-','') {
        background: #{$vendor}linear-gradient(#{$arg1}, #{$arg2});
    }
}

@mixin linear-gradient($name, $arg1, $arg2){
    @each $vendor in ('-webkit-', '-moz-','') {
        background: #{$vendor}$name+'('+$arg1+', '+$arg2+')';
    }
}

#myElement {
    @include linear-gradient(top, 50%);
}

/* Output */

#myElement {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 50%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, 50%);
}
```

Comment: that $name stands for the style 'linear-gradient'. See the edited question.

Comment: the output I'm getting is

Comment: background: -webkit-linear-gradienttop, 50%

Comment: @das I've updated my answer to provide an alternative solution that compiles the parentheses without omitting the `$name` parameter.

Comment: your idea of concatenating '(' using '+' helped. I could do it but with a slight variation as given below.

Comment: background: #{$vendor}linear-gradient + '( '+$arg1+', '+$arg2+') ';